# gcc won't compile to executable in shared folder

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, shared-directory

I have dual boot windows - ubuntu on my laptop. I wanted to have a shared partition for my documents so I  created a fat partition with my files and mounted it on ubuntu.

The problem is the following:

I tried to create a simple "helloworld" program in C language  (I named the file test.c). When the file is in ~/Documents I can compile and run it as expected. When I move test.c in shared directory, a.out file is created but it is not executable. If I chmod +x ./a.out, then the output is ./a.out: command not found.

Any idea?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I don't want the complied version to run on both the operating systems. I only want to be able the run the debugger on ubuntu. and just read and edit the text from windows. any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason may be c language is not platform independent. So code written in one os won't be accessible from other os. As the folder is shared by two os this problem may have raised.

Comment: I only want to be able the run the debugger on ubuntu. and just read and edit the text from windows. any solutions ?